# Why I always get the 0 value even my collection is not empty

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I want dropVolume get the value to use it in another method after calling my  **getAllDropsVolumePerDate(date)** method.
but every time I get **dropVolume** = 0

```
 dropVolume = 0;
  getAllDropsVolumePerDate(date: string) {
    this.campaignService.getAllCampaigns().subscribe((res) => {
      res.forEach((campaign) => {
        campaign.drops.forEach((drop) => {
          if (drop.dropDate === date) {
            this.dropVolume = this.dropVolume +drop.dropVolume;
          }
        });
      });
     return this.dropVolume;
    });
    return this.dropVolume;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Subscription is asynchronous and it can take time to return a value (even if it's in milliseconds), so your subscription starts BUT your return line is out of it and will be triggered before the subscription returns with a value. Move your return line inside the subscription.

Comment: I did it but the interpreter still skipping